# Why is Python OpenCV camera read in Ubuntu slower than Windows?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a really simple code to view video from web-cam (Microsoft HD LifeCam Studio) as follow:

```
import cv2
from imutils.video import FPS

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
fps = FPS().start()

while cap.isOpened():
    _,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    fps.update()
fps.stop()
print("{}".format(fps.fps()))

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code will print out the FPS when the program ends.

When running this code on Windows, I receive 30 FPS. However, when running on Ubuntu, I only receive 10 FPS.

I have tried `cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)` but it does not work.

Does anyone experience the same situation? Is there any solution for this problem?

I'm running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.5.2 
OpenCV 3.4.0

Comment: Generally launching a separate thread for capture gives better FPS results.

Comment: this link might help you https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/

Comment: I have checked the post that you mentioned. However, this is not the "real" FPS. It just shows how many frames your computer can process but not how many frames your computer can display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on how I install the OpenCV framework. In Ubuntu, I use `pip` to install the OpenCV which causes the weak performance. Instead of using `pip`, I built OpenCV from the source code which enhance the performance to the same as in Windows.